# How do I move ~/.fonts without disrupting features?

Tags: fonts, symbolic-link

I have limited space left on my partition, and I just realized that my `~/.fonts` folder is almost 1GB. How should I move it to another partition without any problems?

Comment: Is the other partition going to be always available and mounted? Or is it on an external drive?

Comment: @Andrea Always available and mounted (mounted at startup).

Comment: Do you really need 1GB of fonts, though? Unless maybe you're a graphic designer or something and you really need them, maybe you should do some cleaning up...

Comment: My problem isn't with storage space, it is with the particular partition my install is on. I was playing around with a new desktop environment, and I liked it enough to make it my primary workhorse. Unfortunately, I didn't have the foresight to keep extra space for all my program files.

Comment: @abhidivekar Please check my answer

Comment: @abhidivekar Even if your problem isn't space, be known that 1GB of fonts can be a bottleneck for performance. If you aren't a graphics designer or really in need of those, try disabling some of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can move it to any partition that you want:

```
mv ~/.fonts /path/that/you/want
```

Then edit `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` file and add your directory to this file:

```
sudo nano /etc/fonts/fonts.conf
```

So add your path to the `<!-- Font directory list -->` **section** in that file:

```
    <dir>/usr/share/fonts</dir>
    <dir>/path/that/you/want</dir>
    <dir>/usr/local/share/fonts</dir>
    <dir prefix="xdg">fonts</dir>
    <!-- the following element will be removed in the future -->
    <dir>~/.fonts</dir>
```

Comment: "without disrupting features?" So... why `mv` and not `cp`, then change fonts.conf and then delete it? The `mv` can "disrupting features".

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for your reply, I use `mv` because he says that " have limited space left on my partition" So this partition must be changed. / " then change fonts.conf and then delete it?" No I haven't say that I say "just edit this `.conf` file by `nano`"

Comment: @Rinzwind  I think its because of my bad english. So I use "edit" word instead of "change"

Comment: Okay I used this method and, after a restart, it seems to work fine. I'm going to accept it.

Comment: @ali76 they can copy to an external partition, change the file, then remove the old directory, which would be the 'better' method.

Comment: @ali76 he said he wanted it to another partition ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The method with editing `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` will add the new font path to the font search list for *all* users. This may or may not be what you need.

If you only want to set this up for one user and not share the new directory with other users, you don't even have to gain root privileges: just make a symlink to your new path in place of the original path:

```
cp -r ~/.fonts /new/place/for/your/fonts
mv -v ~/.fonts{,.bak}
ln -sv /new/place/for/your/fonts ~/.fonts
rm -r ~/.fonts.bak
```

This will copy your current `~/.fonts` directory to the new place, rename the original directory, and then, in place of it, create a symbolic link which points to that new font path. After this the renamed original directory is removed.

The rename-and-link approach above is meant to reduce time of unavailability of the `~/.fonts/` directory (to address your *without disrupting features* request). You can use `mv` as in the other answer if you don't need this. The main idea here is to make a symlink instead of editing system-wide font settings.